# Use of undefined constant __DIR__

Tags: php

I am getting following error:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant `__DIR__` - assumed `'__DIR__'` in
>   /home/a2708294/public_html/firebase/index.php on line 58

**Line:58**

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/firebase.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/push.php';
```

Comment: What PHP version are you using? See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) for available magic constants and from which PHP version they're available.

Comment: Upgrade your PHP version to something that hasn't been dead for years.

Answer (score 7):

The magic constant `__DIR__` was added in PHP version 5.3.0
You can check it here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

You need to upgrade php to a newer version. Anyway you need to upgrade because you have a very old version.

If you can't upgrade php you can use `dirname(__FILE__)` as a hack because magic constant `__FILE__` is in PHP from version 4.0.2

So your code will look like this:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/firebase.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/push.php');
```

Answer (score -1):

**DIR** The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to dirname(**FILE**). This directory name does not have a trailing slash unless it is the root directory.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php